# Multiple sessions and graphs in Tensorflow (in the same process)

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, deep-learning

I'm training a model where the input vector is the output of another model. This involves restoring the first model from a checkpoint file while initializing the second model from scratch (using `tf.initialize_variables()`) in the same process.

There is a substantial amount of code and abstraction, so I'm just pasting the relevant sections here.

The following is the restoring code:

```
self.variables = [var for var in all_vars if var.name.startswith(self.name)]
saver = tf.train.Saver(self.variables, max_to_keep=3)
self.save_path = tf.train.latest_checkpoint(os.path.dirname(self.checkpoint_path))

if should_restore:
    self.saver.restore(self.sess, save_path)
else:
    self.sess.run(tf.initialize_variables(self.variables))
```

Each model is scoped within its own graph and session, like this:

```
 self.graph = tf.Graph()
 self.sess = tf.Session(graph=self.graph)

 with self.sess.graph.as_default():
    # Create variables and ops.
```

All the variables within each model are created within the `variable_scope` context manager.

The feeding works as follows:

- A background thread calls `sess.run(inference_op)` on `input = scipy.misc.imread(X)` and puts the result in a blocking thread-safe queue.
- The main training loop reads from the queue and calls `sess.run(train_op)` on the second model.

**PROBLEM:**
I am observing that the loss values, even in the very first iteration of the training (second model) keep changing drastically across runs (and become nan in a few iterations). I confirmed that the output of the first model is exactly the same everytime. Commenting out the `sess.run` of the first model and replacing it with identical input from a pickled file does not show this behaviour.

This is the `train_op`:

```
    loss_op = tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy(network.feedforward())
    # Apply gradients.
    with tf.control_dependencies([loss_op]):
        opt = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(lr)
        grads = opt.compute_gradients(loss_op)
        apply_gradient_op = opt.apply_gradients(grads)

    return apply_gradient_op
```

I know this is vague, but I'm happy to provide more details. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue is most certainly happening due to concurrent execution of different session objects. I moved the first model's session from the background thread to the main thread, repeated the controlled experiment several times (running for over 24 hours and reaching convergence) and never observed `NaN`. On the other hand, concurrent execution diverges the model within a few minutes.

I've restructured my code to use a common session object for all models.

Comment: I am facing exactly same problem. Can you elaborate your solution please?

Comment: Do not run `sess.run` concurrently. Tensorflow assumes complete control of (all exposed) GPU memory. Running `sess.run` in two different processes or threads concurrently will cause issues.

Comment: @Vikesh Can you clarify with a small sample of code please? I have been facing the same issue but not able to find any solution