# How to run tensorflow session inside a default session?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, deep-learning, computer-vision

How to use the prediction of default tensorflow session as input to new tensorflow session. I have a detection model, the detected objects should be passed as input to new model for classification, when i am trying to do I am getting resource exhaust error.
sample code:

```
with detection_graph.as_default():
    with tf.Session(graph=detection_graph) as sess:
        while True:
            sess.run([boxes, scores, classes, num_detections] )

            """ I want to use the predicted values to another tensorflow session for classification"""
           i.e
           with tf.Session() as sess:
               "Classification model"
               "Pseudo code????"
```

Thanks

Comment: what's the motivation behind having 2 sessions in the graph?

Comment: I am trying to run two different models, classification on top custom detection model.

Comment: can you paste the actual error message as opposed to "getting resource exhaust error" ? [Multiple sessions and graphs SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38819576/multiple-sessions-and-graphs-in-tensorflow-in-the-same-process/38889562#38889562) seems to discuss having multiple sessions and it runs (albeit the results are corrupted because of the threaded nature) so I'm not sure the error is because of having nested sessions

Comment: @IanQuah There is no error. But when i observe my log there is continuous print of tensorflow session(is it because of each time creating new session and closing it?). And I made the nested sess as default session but still i am still facing this issue. 
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

After this `with` the session will close because it falls out of scope, so yes, it would be created each iteration of the `while` loop:

```
   with tf.Session() as sess:
       "Classification model"
       "Pseudo code????"
```

I suspect you'd want to re-arrange to something like this:

```
with detection_graph.as_default():
    with tf.Session(graph=detection_graph) as sess:
        sess2 = tf.Session(graph=detection_graph)
        while True:
            sess.run([boxes, scores, classes, num_detections] )

            """ I want to use the predicted values to another tensorflow session for classification"""
            # use sess2 here
            "Classification model"
            "Pseudo code????"
```

Answer (score 0):

After trying all different methods I was able to fix it, using class **init** method.

```
def __init__(self):
    """Tensorflow detector
    """
    self.detection_graph = tf.Graph()
    with self.detection_graph.as_default():
        od_graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
        with tf.gfile.GFile(frozen_inference.pb, 'rb') as fid:
            serialized_graph = fid.read()
            od_graph_def.ParseFromString(serialized_graph)
            tf.import_graph_def(od_graph_def, name='')


    with self.detection_graph.as_default():
        config = tf.ConfigProto()
        # config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True
        self.detection_sess = tf.Session(graph=self.detection_graph, config=config)
        self.windowNotSet = True
```